# Sharing content with domain access?

Tags: users, nodes, domain-access

I setup a site with [domain access](http://drupal.org/project/domain). It has 2 subsites.
I want to publish content from the main site to the subsites. This is already working good with send to affiliates. But I want some local admins on the subsites to have the permission to decide if they want to use the content or not. Is it even possible with domain access or is it just one way from top to bottom ?

Comment: Read this
http://drupal.org/node/1096982
I think this feature are not there yet, try to create request feature if possible

Comment: httpd.conf,httpd.vhost.conf,hosts,settings.php,sites.php are the files which are needed to be configured to start the process

Comment: i am trying to make it work right now with the flag module. so users can flag nodes and views will display them with a flag filter. but i have to write my own, because flag module only supports flagged by user or flagged by any. i have to create a flag views filter for domain user. if anyone can help. would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

One solution I did recently in a similar situation was just create a `views xml feed` of the content I want to feed to my subsites. From there my subsites would have the [feed_import](https://www.drupal.org/project/feed_import) module and have to fetch the articles every 10 minutes. Once fetched it will be unpublished but can only be viewed by certain roles for screening.

Now as for the left over imported nodes I would use `node_purge` to delete nodes that are X days old. Obviously this solution wouldn't be ideal for sites with sensitive data as the xml feed is exposed.

Comment: i considered it too, but at the end its to much redundant data within one domain access site + subdomains.